# Three.js - Using box3 to scale and translate an object

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a piece of code that loads up a 3D image which initially isn't visible. It is supposed to be visible, however, after scaling and translating it, but no matter what I do, the screen remains black and I cannot see the 3D image.

I won't post the entire code but here's the section about the scaling and translating (the code portions that I've commented out is what I tried to implement as the solution):

```
const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
// object.scale.set( 2, 2, 2 );
// box.getCenter(object.position);
// object.geometry.center();

scene.add( object );
```

I'm confused whether I'm misunderstanding Box3, whether it has to do with the order in which I'm scaling/centering, or if it's my values, or something trivial that I'm forgetting to add.

EDIT: I believe that I need to properly size the bounding box around the image, and use that to scale the tiger. I'm still confused about this, because I assumed this line already did that:

```
const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
```

So I'm not sure how I can change the size of the bounding box so it is correct, and then scale it to the size I want.

Comment: Have you verified that  `object` can be made visible if added to the scene without scaling to rule out that the object itself is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I was told that the object just needs to be correctly scaled and centered using the properties of its bounding box to be visible.